# XSL translator which removes blank space and convert inches to feet

Tags: xml, xslt

I need XSL which can do following things:-

1. Remove all empty attributes
2. Any attribute which has UOM in name and value is IN i need to change its value to FEET
3. All the attributes which contain Length, Width, Height in name i need to convert values to feet (need to multiple by .083)

For my first requirement i am using this xsl:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*[not(normalize-space(.))]">
        <xsl:if test="descendant::*/@*[not(normalize-space(.))]">
            <xsl:copy />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input you can assume something like:-

```
<Input BlankAttribute="" HeightUOM="IN" Height="1" WidthUOM="IN" WIdth="2" RandomAttribute="random"/>
```

Comment: The first template you have is the right starting point, the second has the right match pattern but should simply be empty (`<xsl:template match="@*[not(normalize-space(.))]"/>`) to delete the empty attributes. Then add further templates for the cases you have e.g. `<xsl:template match="@*[contains(local-name(), 'UOM') and . = 'IN']"><xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">FEET</xsl:attribute></xsl:template>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*[not(normalize-space(.))]"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*[contains(local-name(), 'UOM') and . = 'IN']">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">FEET</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*[contains(local-name(), 'Height') or contains(local-name(), 'Width') or contains(local-name(), 'Length')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:value-of select=". * 0.83"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

then I think all your conditions are implemented, online sample is at http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38Z4